Need advice on first job switch
I'm a SOC analyst with 3.5 yrs of experience. In 3.5 years, I had a promotion and my CTC is more than doubled and I'm expecting another promotion in 1 year and then slow transition to another field according to my career goals.
Should I wait or switch?
